How can I make my PWA work Offline Without Internet?
I've tried to play with the service worker but it seems like the app can't work offline. When I'm not connected to the internet it shows a blank page with You are Offline title.
My App was created with Laravel for the Backend and React (NextJs) for the front end.
Here is my service-worker file: https://pastebin.com/RmAUsG7M
